# Countable/Cocountable $\sigma$ Algebra and a measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be an uncountable set, $M\subset P(X)$ be the collection of subsets for which each element, $A$ is countable, or $A^c$ is countable.

Define the measure:

$\mu:M \to [0,\infty]$ by

$\mu(A) = 1$ if $A^c$ is countable,  $\mu(A) = 0$ if $A$ is countable.

I've shown $(X,M,\mu)$ is a measure-space.

I need help with:

$f:X\to [0,\infty]$ is measurable implies that:

$\exists a \in [0,\infty]$ s.t $\{x\in X$ | $\{f(x) \neq a \}$ is at most countable.

I've tried several things:

1. build a sequence of closed balls in $[0,\infty]$, with radius converging to zero, for which the pre-image of each, must contain an uncountable number of $x\in X$. This sequence must have a limit $a_0$, but I couldn't finish and show  $\{x\in X$ | $\{f(x) \neq a_0 \}$ is at most countable.
2. Considered the intervals $(i,\infty] \cup [0,i)$ and the negation of the statement.

Any help please?

Comment: If you partition $[0,\infty]$ into countably (that includes finitely) many disjoint measurable sets, precisely one of those has uncountable preimage under $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer ok, do you suggest a particular partition, or will $[0,1) \cup [1,\infty]$ suffice? if so, I've gotten there, but didn't see why it implies the statement

Comment: If you managed to construct your shrinking sequence of balls, look at $[0,a_0) \cup \{a_0\} \cup (a_0,\infty]$ and prove that $f^{-1}([0,a_0))$ and $f^{-1}((a_0,\infty])$ are countable (by writing the intervals as a countable union of smaller intervals or otherwise).